# Debugging JSP pages in WebLogic

Tags: eclipse, jsp, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I need to debug some JSP pages, served by WebLogic. So I set up the remote debug in Eclipse, set the appropriate port number.

It seems to work, since entering in debug perspective and stopping the exceution actually works. Unfortunately when setting a breakpoint on a JSP, the BP doesn't work.

I am sure I am setting the BP on the right page, unless some strange transformation is made on the JSP I upload to the server.

I found [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15051_01/wlw/docs103/guide/ideuserguide/servers/conWebLogicServer.html) that these line in weblogic.xml should do the trick

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<weblogic-web-app xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
    <jsp-descriptor>
        <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
<working-dir>theWD</working-dir>
        <backward-compatible>true</backward-compatible>
        <debug>true</debug>
    </jsp-descriptor>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</weblogic-web-app>
```

I actually have these lines in weblogic.xml, in the *theWD* directory i have all the `.java` files with name as follow: foreach *.jsp file

```
name.jsp -->  __name.java
```

I also added the *theWD* folder to eclipse source lookup, but still no result.

Comment: At the moment I still can't find any solution to this and do not have any clue about where the problem is located.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't set a breakpoint directly in JSP; however, you can trick your debugger into letting you do essentially the same thing.

Since it's JSP, you are able to call a method in a Java class.  Put a test line that calls that method right before whatever line in the JSP file you want your breakpoint to be on.   Find that Java class, set a breakpoint in the method being called, and then trace up through the stack until you get back to your JSP file.

Comment: Nice idea, I guess in that case I will end uo in the java generated from the jsp file.